# Count the number of lines starting with particular string - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to count the number of strings in a text file starting with particular string only

```
function count = countLines(fname)
fh = fopen(fname, 'rt');
assert(fh ~= -1, 'Could not read: %s', fname);
x = onCleanup(@() fclose(fh));
count = 0;
while ~feof(fh)
count = count + sum( fread( fh, 16384, 'char' ) == char(10) );
end
count = count+1;
end
```

I am using the above function to count the number of lines in the whole .text file. But now I wanted to find the number of lines starting with only with particular strings (Eg. All the lines starting with a letter 's').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two **[`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html)** based approaches here.

**Approach #1**

```
str1 = 's';  %// search string 

%// Read in text data into a cell array with each cell holding text data from 
%// each line of text file
textdata = importdata(fname,'\n') ;

%// Compare each cell's  starting n characters for the search string, where 
%// n is no. of chars in search string and sum those matches for the final count
count = sum(cellfun(@(x) strncmp(x,str1,numel(str1)),textdata))
```

---

**Approach #2**

```
%// ..... Get str1 and textdata as shown in Approach #1

%// Convert cell array data into char array
char_textdata = char(textdata) 

%// Select the first n columns from char array and compare against search
%// string for all characters match and sum those matches for the final count.
%// Here n is the number of characters in search string
count = sum(all(bsxfun(@eq,char_textdata(:,1:numel(str1)),str1),2))
```

With both these approaches, you can even specify a char array as search string.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't get the idea behind your code, so I cannot modify it I use this approach:

```
fid = fopen(txt);

% Loop through data file until we get a -1 indicating EOF
while(x ~= (-1))
    line = fgetl(fid);
    r = r+1;
end
r = r-1;
```

with `r` being the number of lines in the file. You can easily check the value of `line` before increasing the counter `r` to meet your condition first.

Also I don't know what are the performance issues regarding those two methods.